# Cannot convert value of type to expected argument type?

Tags: swift, function, button, ibaction, for-in-loop

I am trying to utilize a function to set properties for different buttons. Here is the area of code the error is occurring:

```
@IBAction func pHTargetButton(sender: UIButton) {
    let buttonArray = [chemistryButton0!, chemistryButton1!, chemistryButton2!, chemistryButton3!, chemistryButton4!, chemistryButton5!]
    let chemistryViewChoice = ["pH"]
    for var i in 0..<buttonArray.count {
        setButton(ChemistryViewInfo, button: buttonArray[i], i)
        if buttonArray.count<5 {
            chemistryButton5?.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 255, green:  255, blue: 255)
            chemistryButton5?.setTitle("", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
            chemistryButton5?.alpha = 0.0} else{}}}
```

The error occurs when I call the setButton function. The error highlights the ChemistryViewInfo part of the function.

The error is:

`Cannot convert value of type "ChemistryViewInfo.Type" to expected argument type "ChemistryViewInfo".`

Here is the function I have created and am calling:

```
func setButton(viewInfo:ChemistryViewInfo,button:UIButton, index:Int) {
    let buttonInfo = viewInfo.buttons[index]
    button.titleLabel?.text = buttonInfo.scale
    button.backgroundColor = buttonInfo.color
}
```

I am wondering if this is because there is an error in my code or I am doing the wrong thing. I have al the buttons declared correctly so I know that is not the problem. Anyways, please help.

Any suggestions or input are greatly appreciated. Please post the changed code in your answer.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

Here is the code that I am drawing from:

```
struct ChemistryButtonInfo{
let scale: String
let color: UIColor
let levelExamp: String
let levelInfo: String
}

struct ChemistryViewInfo {

let text: String
let description: String
let buttons: [ChemistryButtonInfo]
}


let chemistryViewChoice = ["pH":
ChemistryViewInfo(
    text: "pH",
    description: "Most living things depend on proper pH level to sustain life.",
    buttons: [
        ChemistryButtonInfo(scale: "6.2", color: UIColor(red: 212, green: 142, blue: 69), levelExamp: "Bread, Salmon, Potatoes, Normal Rain, Milk", levelInfo: "This level is not dangerous for humans. Only dangerous to some plant life."),
        ChemistryButtonInfo(scale: "6.8", color: UIColor(red: 209, green: 122, blue: 31), levelExamp: "Milk and Human Saliva", levelInfo: "This level is not dangerous fr humans but on ly dangerouse to some plant life"),
        ChemistryButtonInfo(scale: "7.2", color: UIColor(red: 224, green:  80, blue:  9), levelExamp: "Blood, Human Tears, and Pure Water", levelInfo: "This level is not dangerous for humans. Only dangerous to few species of plant life."),
        ChemistryButtonInfo(scale: "7.8", color: UIColor(red: 194, green:  74, blue: 58), levelExamp: "Sea Water and Eggs", levelInfo: "This level is not dangerous for humans, plants or fish"),
        ChemistryButtonInfo(scale: "8.4", color: UIColor(red: 208, green:  48, blue: 75), levelExamp: "Baking Soda and Phosphate Detergents", levelInfo: "This level is sometimes, in rare cases, dangerous for humans. Also dangerous to certain species of plant life and marine life." )]),
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming ChemistryViewInfo is a class name. You need to send an instance of ChemistryViewInfo to setButton. Something like:

```
@IBAction func pHTargetButton(sender: UIButton) {
    let buttonArray = [chemistryButton0!, chemistryButton1!, chemistryButton2!, chemistryButton3!, chemistryButton4!, chemistryButton5!]

    for var i in 0..<buttonArray.count {
        setButton(chemistryViewChoice["pH"], button: buttonArray[i], i)
        if buttonArray.count<5 {
            chemistryButton5?.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 255, green:  255, blue: 255)
            chemistryButton5?.setTitle("", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
            chemistryButton5?.alpha = 0.0} else{}
        }
     }
}
```

Comment: Will this set the title and background color for every button?

Comment: @Bigfoot11 use `chemistryViewChoice["pH"]` but remove the chemistryViewChoice from the function.